# How to get private key from litecoin-qt wallet?

Tags: wallet.dat, litecoin-qt

I want to backup only the private key, not the full litecoin-qt wallet for the reason that the wallet can be used only with litecoin-qt client and if I have to use it after few years or on other machine, I do not want to wait the client to fully download the full blockchain.

Could anyone please let me know how to extract the private key from the wallet file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go in the console and type : dumpprivkey *litecoinaddress*

Use the help if nessassary.

The console is in : Help\Debug Windows

Comment: and if there is passphrase for the wallet, type the following cmd before it: walletpassphrase <your_pass_phrase>